# Interact with a component opened in another window

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-components

In my project I need to display 2 different components in 2 different screens. So I open two browser windows and display those components.
I was wondering if it's possible to interact from a component in the first window to another in the second one?

I tried creating a `Subject` in a Service. but whenever I try to subscribe to this Subject in the component of the other window it doesn't work. Here is what I do:

```
export class MyService {
  public navigationTrigger: Subject<NavigationParams> = new Subject();

  constructor(private _http: Http) {
    this.navigationTrigger.next(params);
  }
}
```

And in a component I subscribe to it :

```
this.watsonService.navigationTrigger.subscribe((navigation) => {
   this.updateNavigation(navigation);
});
```

But doesn't work. I'm not sure how to achieve what I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subscribing to a Subject will not work, because it lives only in the scope of that single Window.

If you want to use it for real-time communication with two different users, than you should use WebSockets.
If it is the same user, than you can use localStorage.

Sender part

```
    localStorage.setItem("someKey", "someValue");
```

Receiver part

```
    window.addEventListener('storage', storageEventHandler, false);

    function storageEventHandler(evt) {
        alert("storage event called key: " + evt.key);
    }
```

And you can wrap it inside Observable too, see this example

```
    Rx.Observable.create(observer => {
     window.addEventListener('storage', storageEventHandler, false);

     function storageEventHandler(evt) {
         alert("storage event called key: " + evt.key);
         observer.onNext(evt);
     }
     // todo: return unsubscribe function which will remove that eventListener

});
```

Answer (score -1):

Above answer provided by David will work.
Especially since Angular 2 isn’t only designed to run within your browser, but also on mobile, the server or web workers where objects like window may not be available.

Therefore the suggested approach is to wrap such objects and inject them through the dependency injection mechanism. This way it is possible to change the concrete run time instance of a given object based on the environment the Angular application is running. The result we wanna achieve is the following:

```
import { WindowRef } from './WindowRef';
@Component({...})
class MyComponent {
    constructor(private winRef: WindowRef) {
        // getting the native window obj
        console.log('Native window obj', winRef.nativeWindow);
     }
}
```

A very straightforward and easy way to wrap window is by creating an Angular 2 service. That’s as easy as creating an ES6 class and decorating it with @Injectable.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
function _window() : any {
   // return the global native browser window object
   return window;
}
@Injectable()
export class WindowRef {
   get nativeWindow() : any {
      return _window();
   }
}
```

Register WindowRef as Provider

```
 @NgModule({
    ...
    providers: [ WindowRef ]
 })
 export class AppModule{}
```